# Why are the sky distributions of SDSS DR16 and DR16Q different?

Tags: coordinate, sky-survey

I've downloaded the csv files for [SDSS DR16](https://vizier.cds.unistra.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-3?-source=V/154&-out.max=50&-out.form=HTML%20Table&-out.add=_r&-out.add=_RAJ,_DEJ&-sort=_r&-oc.form=sexa) and [DR16Q](https://vizier.cds.unistra.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-3?-source=VII/289&-out.max=50&-out.form=HTML%20Table&-out.add=_r&-out.add=_RAJ,_DEJ&-sort=_r&-oc.form=sexa) and made a map of their sky distributions:

[image]

The coordinates come from:

- DR16: `RA_ICRS` and `DE_ICRS`
- DR16Q: `RAJ2000` and `DEJ2000`

Why do they overlap only partly? Isn't DR16Q a subset of DR16?

Comment: Stupid question but have you checked you're getting the full catalog or subsampling the complete catalog (every 100th row or something throughout the full dataset) ? If the two catalog's rows are arranged differently, then if you have a hit a row limit in the extraction, you would get different sky coverage... just a thought

Comment: @astrosnapper I thought of that, but I'm pretty sure I downloaded the files using the default settings from VizieR, and I've checked; they seem to be the full samples.